# Spock Unit test with a closure ends with error "No runnable methods"

Tags: java, groovy, junit, gradle, spock

I wrote a simple feature method with the following `then` block :

```
then:
1 * view.setAttachments({ it?.size == 3 })
```

But the `gradle test` fails with the error :

```
initializationError

java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:169)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:104)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    ...

initializationError

java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:147)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    ...
```

I noticed that if I remove the closure, there is no more error

```
then:
1 * view.setAttachments(_) // everything works well without closure!
```

It seems Spock tries to run the closure like it was another test method... How to avoid that ?

Comment: It's likely that the problem is somewhere else (please post a self-contained example). It looks like the spec isn't executed by Spock but by JUnit. This won't work, even if it doesn't cause an exception.

Comment: agree, because it executes without error on an other machine... Will recheck tomorrow on my office computer.

Comment: OK finally found why, this is because I run a single test with `-Dtest.single=MyTest` which seems to automatically invoke the JUnit test runner instead of the Spock one. What is the correct way to run a single test from command line with Spock and Gradle ? (if it exists)

Comment: Usually, `-Dtest.single` works just fine for Spock tests. Can you provide a self-contained reproducible example? Which Gradle version?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem trying to write a spring-boot test.

Do not use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and try removing your junit runner if you're using another one.

For me my Spock Specification executed properly without specifying the SpringRunner.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the issue in my case is that the test file/class ended with `Test`, rather than `Spec`. Changing that resolved the issue (e.g. `SomeServiceTest` -> `SomeServiceSpec`).

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure out that. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me worked moving the test file from "src" directory to "Test" directory.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following property to your build.gradle

```
 test {
        systemProperty 'project.buildDir', project.buildDir
    }
```